# SQL Server foreign key, referenced tables

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2005

Is there a tool or someone does have a query that can for provided table make a query that will have (left) joins on all referenced tables and subsequently all other tables that are referenced by those etc... to the n-th lvl.

Thanks

Comment: This can be accomplished, however so is a place for help and not just a "I need a script" environment. People will ask for you to show your code in which you've attempted first.

Comment: Ok, how about this: SELECT *.

Comment: Basicly, i need to do a replication of SQL server 2005 database, and i have 1 main table that have 'user' info. Across 2100 tables i have in database, and relations set up, i have to copy every single row of data from every table that is linked to the 'user' table... if needed i can paste my script with 2500 rows, but i recon that ppl do not want to waste time on it. I know exact problem, but I'm unable to solve it.

Comment: Ok give me 5-10 minutes, you can use sys tables to build the relationships up and then dynamic SQL to plug it together and run.

Comment: Thx. deleting that data after replication is eazy mode. disable constraints, drop user table row, and nuke all 'orphans' in every table that is referencing main one via sys.foreign_keys, and do the same thing on other tables. The issue i have is copying the tables that are 'lvl4' but are referencing lvl1 and lvl3 tables that are also propagating to the main one. If you catch my drift. I can skech it if needed.

Comment: I have put together a script that left joins all tables that are referenced tables to a given table but it doesn't carry on going down. You'll essentially just have to re use the logic.

Comment: What would you like it to do when there are loops of tables that reference one another?  Stop at level _n_ where that value is supplied as a parameter?

Comment: Actualy yes. I have 'root/main' table that represent user. Most tables are referencing that table or they are referencing it over some 'parent' table.Basicly i want to do a replication of all user data to another DB. So i need to recalculate all FK id-s in targeted DB. I have 2200 tables, and it is a paint to write that stuff manualy. It isnt problem to make lvl 1 joins (go to sys.foreign_keys and just write it), but problem is making it 2nd lvl or greater.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you can use sp_CascadingDataViewer (http://cascadingdataviewer.codeplex.com/) to extract the data and then cut and paste to the new database. I am sure it can be modified to output all dynamic sql in the process and that can be run in reverse order to fill the new database too.